# Javascript Transducers for a Data Flow project

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, stream

with my current project, I am dealing with large streams of numerical data and transformations that have to take place on them in a data-flow-programmable fashion.

I stumbled upon the idea of transducers, which promised to solve the difficulties to handle multiple transformations on large arrays. It seems that transducers don't suit exactly for what I'm trying to solve here.

I am looking for a pattern / concept for transducers which only collect a needed amount of lookback to then process out a result. Similar to the browser version of tensorflow, reaktor, max-msp (input outputs, flow-graphs, node-based, visual-programming)

Most of these modules, should be connected to a source, but should also be able to act as a source to chain those to other modules

```
source ( a stream ) =[new-value]|=> module1 => module2 => ...
                                |=> module3 => module4 // branch off here to a new chain
```

From my understanding, the transducers as explained in most blogs takes the whole array, and feeds each individual values trough chosen transformers.

Yet my modules/transformers don't require so much data to work, say the example of a simple moving average with a look back of 4 steps.

I imagine that module to collect enough data until it starts it's output.
I also don't need to hold the whole array in memory, I should only deal with the exact amounts needed. Results/Outputs would be optionally stored in a database.

```
stream =[sends-1-value]=> module[collects-values-until-processing-starts] =[sends-one-value]=>...
```

It should also be possible to connect multiple sources into a module (which transducers didn't seem to provide.

Would the transducer pattern here still apply or is something else out there?

To be honest, every programmer would have an idea to make this work, yet I am asking for some established way of doing it, just like transducers came to be.

Comment: Transducers are just compositions of arbitrarily composed transformations with a binary `append` function (in the sense of a semigroup). But you need to feed such a transducer to a `fold` function of a `Foldable` data type. If you use a lazy right fold this is halfway to streams, which is the data type you are probably looking for.

Comment: Please provide us a sample input and the expected output so that we can better understand your question. As it currently stands, it's difficult to answer your question because it's not objective. Your question requires more focus.

Comment: the streams ( sources ) would be emitting one value at a time, possibly numbers or objects, but let's stick to numbers. each node after that should have the ability to collect values until a computation takes place within that ( example moving average ) , which in turn outputs another single value. binding multiple sources to one node or inputting multiple sources to one node should be possible too. in a nutshell it's like some sort of chain reaction where in the end, a collection of these values can be made, or written into a database. we don't want to hold all recorded values in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **transducer** pattern certainly applies here. You can create a floating point processor with transducers paired with the right data structure. I'll give you a baseline example, with one assumption:

1. the stream you are working with implements [Symbol.asyncIterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/asyncIterator)

Consider a simple queue

```js
function SimpleQueue({ size }) {
  this.size = size
  this.buffer = []
}

SimpleQueue.prototype.push = function(item) {
  this.buffer.push(item)
  if (this.buffer.length > this.size) {
    this.buffer.shift()
  }
  return this
}

SimpleQueue.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function*() {
  for (const item of this.buffer) {
    yield item
  }
}
```

Our simple queue has one method `push` that pushes an item into its internal buffer (an array). The simple queue is also iterable, so you could do `for (const x of simpleQueue) {/* stuff */}`

We'll now use our `SimpleQueue` in our floating point processor.

```js
const average = iterable => {
  let sum = 0, count = 0
  for (const item of iterable) {
    sum += item
    count += 1
  }
  return sum / count
}

const floatingPointAverage = ({ historySize }) => {
  const queue = new SimpleQueue({ size: historySize })
  return item => {
    queue.push(item)
    const avg = average(queue)
    console.log(queue, avg) // this shows the average as the process runs
    return avg
  }
}
```

`floatingPointAverage` takes an item, pushes it into our `SimpleQueue`, and returns the current average of items in the queue.

Finally, we can implement and consume our transducer

```js
const { pipe, map, transform } = require('rubico')

const numbersStream = {
  [Symbol.asyncIterator]: async function*() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) yield i
  },
}

transform(
  pipe([
    map(floatingPointAverage({ historySize: 4 })),
    /* transducers that do stuff with floating point average here */
  ]),
  null,
)(numbersStream)
```

The **transducer** in this case is `map(floatingPointAverage({ historySize: 4 }))`. This transducer is courtesy of **rubico**, a library I wrote to solve my own async problems. I write about transducers in the context of rubico [here](https://github.com/richytong/rubico#transducers)

Your output should look like this

```
SimpleQueue { size: 4, buffer: [ 0 ] } 0
SimpleQueue { size: 4, buffer: [ 0, 1 ] } 0.5
SimpleQueue { size: 4, buffer: [ 0, 1, 2 ] } 1
SimpleQueue { size: 4, buffer: [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ] } 1.5
SimpleQueue { size: 4, buffer: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] } 2.5
SimpleQueue { size: 4, buffer: [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ] } 3.5
SimpleQueue { size: 4, buffer: [ 3, 4, 5, 6 ] } 4.5
SimpleQueue { size: 4, buffer: [ 4, 5, 6, 7 ] } 5.5
SimpleQueue { size: 4, buffer: [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ] } 6.5
SimpleQueue { size: 4, buffer: [ 6, 7, 8, 9 ] } 7.5
```